# Wakeup Android Oreo Go phone with broken power button

Tags: power-on

I have an Android Oreo Go/Nokia 1 phone which is fine, except the power on/off button is broken.

Right now, the only way I found to wake it up to type the PIN is either connecting it to a charging cable or removing the battery.

There is no setting under display to activate double tap to wake it up.

Volume buttons are fine, but don´t wake phone.

Until I repair the power button (if at all), how can I wake it?

PS: power button came miraculously back to life (after a day not using the phone). I imagine the question can still be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Power Button to Volume Button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teliapp.powervolume&hl=en_IN). It turns the volume button into the power button. Thumbs up!